# How to update links attribute in ember data dynamically?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

To load async relationship ember data payload usually contains `links` attribute.

```
{
  "post": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Progressive Enhancement is Dead",
    "links": {
      "user": "/people/tomdale"
    },
  },
}
```

In my case application have to create link itself due to the fact that it operate on date and time selected by the user. Link to the relationship is not fixed. It there any way to change model `link` attribute on runtime or do I really need to create whole relationship manually using `Ember.$.ajax`?

Comment: I think you can still pass the id (as string) and rely on what you defined in your adapter. Try that maybe...

Comment: Thanks for advice but I don't fully understand what you mean. Where should I pass the id? You are talking about creating own relationship method as I did so far?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant in the serializer! I'm gonna write a proper answer in a minute

Answer (score 1):

You can create a serializer to customize the `links` field. Example:

```
App.PostSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    normalizePayload: function(payload) {
      payload.links = {
        "user": getMyLink(payload.links, payload.id)
      };
      return payload;
    }
});
```

where `getMyLink` is your custom function.

Does this address your problem?

Comment: It probably would solve the case but not this time. I already have one relationship called `links`, so changing payload involes overwriting it. Renaming it accros whole application would take too much time. Moreover, `PostSerializer` is not executed when `post` is embedded into other payload. I was rather thinking that there is some ember API to insert such links.